# Firebug - Apply Settings to IP Range

Tags: firefox, firebug

I realize this isn't strictly programming related, but since it has to do with a common development tool, I figured it was still appropriate.

I am developing a website and my main access to the code is via a virtual machine whose IP address changes every 2-3 days. It is getting very annoying to have to re-apply settings for Firebug every time my IP changes. Is there a way to apply it to a wildcard address like

```
192.168.1.*
```

This would help out immeasurably! Thanks very much for any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug 1.4 seems to have adapted a model where if the FB panel is open, it's enabled without respect to a given site's host.

If you're not able to or comfortable with using an alpha version, you might look into a static IP, DHCP reservation, DDNS or a hosts file entry (which may only move the problem) so you can get some consistency.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out the alpha version. I thought about a DHCP reservation, but I'm on a corporate network, so I have no control over that. Thanks for the info on 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some kind of proxy or tunnel on your local system. When the address changes, you reconfigure your service, but Firebug always points to 127.0.0.1.